# Display all parent folders in Python

Tags: python, tokenize

This falls under the category of asking a question for the sake of answering it (though I will accept answers if they are  better than mine)

How does one print out the absolute paths of all parent folders of a given subfolder. Given the following

```
'/home/marx/Documents/papers/communism'
```

Return

```
[
  '/',
  '/home',
  '/home/marx',
  '/home/marx/Documents',
  '/home/marx/Documents/papers',
  '/home/marx/Documents/papers/communism'
]
```

**Note** The code does not have to check that the file exists, but I don't want bogus output if there is a trailing forward slash, surrounding spaces, or two side by side forward slashes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the functions from module `os.path` - it's platform independent for one thing, i.e. same code will work for Windows paths (when run on a Windows installation).

Use of `os.path.normpath()` elegantly handles duplicate and trailing path separators as well as paths that include "..". Use this instead of `os.path.abspath()` as you will get different results when run from different directories on non-absolute paths.

```
import os.path

def get_parents(path):
    parents = []
    path = os.path.normpath(path)
    while path:
        parents.insert(0, path)
        if path == '/':
            path = ''
        else:
            path = os.path.dirname(path)

    return parents

>>> print get_parents('')
['.']
>>> print get_parents('/')
['/']
>>> print get_parents('/////')
['/']
>>> print get_parents('/home/marx/Documents/papers/communism')
['/', '/home', '/home/marx', '/home/marx/Documents', '/home/marx/Documents/papers', '/home/marx/Documents/papers/communism']
>>> print get_parents('/home/marx/Documents/papers/communism/')
['/', '/home', '/home/marx', '/home/marx/Documents', '/home/marx/Documents/papers', '/home/marx/Documents/papers/communism']
>>> print get_parents('////home/marx////Documents/papers/communism/////')
['/', '/home', '/home/marx', '/home/marx/Documents', '/home/marx/Documents/papers', '/home/marx/Documents/papers/communism']
>>> print get_parents('home/marx////Documents/papers/communism/////')
['home', 'home/marx', 'home/marx/Documents', 'home/marx/Documents/papers', 'home/marx/Documents/papers/communism']
>>> print get_parents('/home/marx////Documents/papers/communism/////../Das Kapital/')
['/', '/home', '/home/marx', '/home/marx/Documents', '/home/marx/Documents/papers', '/home/marx/Documents/papers/Das Kapital']
>>> print get_parents('/home/marx////Documents/papers/communism/////../Das Kapital/')
['/', '/home', '/home/marx', '/home/marx/Documents', '/home/marx/Documents/papers', '/home/marx/Documents/papers/Das Kapital']
>>> print get_parents('/home/marx////Documents/papers/communism/////../Das Kapital/../../../../../../')
['/']
```

Comment: This is the best of all of the answers. Small note, on a mac at least (don't have linux at home), leading or trailing spaces lead to bizarre behaviour.

Comment: @puk: bizarre behaviour? In *nix spaces are a valid file/directory name, e.g. `'   /a/b/c/d    '` is valid. It decomposes into `['   ', '   /a', '   /a/b', '   /a/b/c', '   /a/b/c/d    ']`

Comment: @puk: you did have the stripping of spaces as a requirement, but they can indeed be valid names. If you really want them out, use  '/a/b/c/d '.strip().

Answer (score 1):

Should handle mostly everything.

```
import os

def parents(x, sep = os.path.sep):
    x = os.path.normpath(x)
    if x == sep: # bail out if only leading '/'s
        return [x, ]
    elements = x.split(sep)
    res = list(sep.join(elements[:i]) for i in range(1, len(elements)+1))
    res[0] = sep # fix leading /
    return res



>>> x = '/home/marx/Documents///papers/communism/'
>>> parents(x) 
['/',
 '/home',
 '/home/marx',
 '/home/marx/Documents',
 '/home/marx/Documents/papers',
 '/home/marx/Documents/papers/communism']
```

**edit:** handle properly "parents('////')"

**edit:** simplify the code by adding an optional parameter "sep", and use normpath() (as noted in an other answer)

Comment: Looks a lot cleaner than my version. I'll try it out tomorrow. If it works I'll accept this

Comment: Not earth shattering, but fails for `parents('////')`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os;
import sys;

def stripDoubleSlash(fullPath):
    if fullPath:
        replaced = fullPath.replace('//','/');
        if replaced.find('//') >= 0:
            return stripDoubleSlash(replaced);
        else:
            return replaced;
    return fullPath;
def printAllParents(fullPath):
    tokens = stripDoubleSlash(fullPath).rstrip('/').split('/');
    for i in xrange(0,len(tokens)):
        if i == 0 and not fullPath[0] == '/':
            print tokens[0];
        else:
            print '/'.join(tokens[0:i])+'/'+tokens[i];
if __name__ == '__main__':
    printAllParents(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '/home/marx/Documents/papers/communism/');
```

Answer (score -1):

This minimal block works well, with the exception of failing if there are multiple side by side forward slashes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

def getParents ( path ):    
   parents = [ path ]
   while path != '/':
      path = os.path.dirname ( path )
      parents.append ( path )
   parents.reverse()
   return parents 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print getParents ( '/home/marx/Documents/papers/communism' )
```

Comment: @EliBendersky Do I not need it? I remember it causing problems a while b ack